# Is "unsubstantiate" used correctly as a verb?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

I tried to register my mom for a regular zoom meeting, and I gave her email to the host of the zoom. After the meeting was over, I received this message from the host:

> [image]
> (She unsubstantiated- maybe by mistake)

When I asked what that actually means there was no answer. Did she 'unsubstantiate' or her account? <sub>*(the automatic corrector has already underlined 'unsubstantiate' as incorrect)*</sub> Intrigued, I tried to [google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=unsubstantiate%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsZt2Bk_TGj_9FLrAWUzOFCc72Cpxw%3A1658735404096&ei=LEveYqu8BcW28gKjsovABg&ved=0ahUKEwirgqb0xpP5AhVFm1wKHSPZAmgQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=unsubstantiate%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBwgjELECECcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAc6BwgAEEcQsAM6BwgAELADEENKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQyhBYyhBg0hZoAXABeACAAUOIAUOSAQExmAEAoAEByAEKwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) and most entries I got are definitions of the adjective ***unsubstantiated***.

I did find the verb in [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unsubstantiate):

> to divest of substantiality : make unsubstantial

but I did not perfectly understand how this verb applies in this context. Is this technical jargon? Why not say ***disappeared*** or ***terminated*** or something which could explain what happened to her email or account?

Comment: It sounds like a mistake/mistranslation. Was the person a native English speaker, or coming from another language?

Comment: Not native, but raised in England (with IT studies).

Comment: Maybe there was a fee, and they want more than she paid?

Comment: @Xanne The host is paying for the zoom, users attend for free.

Comment: It looks like an "auto-correct" mistake for "unsubscribed".

Comment: It's user interface jargon, and that's notoriously subject to _Nerdview_, as [this makes clear](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=38076). Software is as software does, and takes its own internal language with it.[

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, this reads something like _"Keyboard not attached. Press F5 to continue."_ :)

Comment: @Greybeard I am beginning to think that maybe that's what happened...

Comment: This person's use of the word is highly idiosyncratic. We can try to **guess** what may have been meant by it, but such guessing is unlikely to be of use to the future visitors to this site.

Comment: @jsw29 The future visitors of this site will have learnt that there is such a thing as Nerdview and user interface jargon at least.

Comment: @JohnLawler, do you have any evidence that this is a part of a jargon, as opposed to being peculiar to this one person, or an auto-correct error?

Comment: it's almost certainly the wrong word. Sessions are instantiated, dropping the session would be the opposite. That may be it, but either way, this isn't proper jargon.

Comment: The M-W definition clearly points to a verb “unsubstantiate” (to divest …”). The question therefore relates to the use of that verb and not to suppositions about circumstance. It may not be an easy matter, but answers should focus on how an invitation and registration may be divested of substance. Leave open.

Comment: Can you provide a more useful example? 'She unsubstantiated - maybe by mistake' offers fewer clues than you hoped, at best.

Answer (score -1):

This is clearly not a clear or standard use of the term, but it also does not seem incorrect. This seems to be intended to mean that she left the meeting, making her digital presence vanish (or in his words, unsubstantiated).

Comment: This seems to describe "unsubscribed".

Comment: No, not unsubscribed. Unsubscribed implies a subscription, where someone agrees to some recurring service. If something is present and distinct it can be described as substantial. For something to unsubstantiate for a physical object would mean to cease to become firmly physically present -- thats the sort of thing you might find in a fictional description of a wizard vanishing. That's the sort of use here, but for a digital presence vanishing.